# Aggregate to create dynamic key from value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation expression as the following:

```
db.Booking.aggregate([
      { $match: { created_at: {$exists:true} } },
      { $sort : { created_at : -1 } },
      { $group: {
          _id: {
            year : { $year : "$created_at" },
            month : { $month : "$created_at" },
            accepted: '$accepted'
          },
          total: {
            $sum: '$total'
          }
        } 
      }
    ])
```

Which generates results like this:

```
[
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":4,"accepted":"expired"},"total":0},
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":4,"accepted":"Expired"},"total":25},
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":4,"accepted":"Pending"},"total":390},
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":5,"accepted":"Pending"},"total":1400}
]
```

And how do I get a result like this:

```
[
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":4},"expired":0},
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":4},"Expired":25},
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":4},"Pending":390},
  {"_id":{"year":2017,"month":5},"Pending":1400}
]
```

Do I have to modify using regular javascript instead of relying Mongodb to do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really "should" process the results to name these keys in your receiving code rather than relying on the database to do this. Whilst possible with the most recent current release it does require some wrangling.

This does require **MongoDB 3.4** at least:

```js
db.Booking.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "created_at": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$sort": { "created_at": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$created_at" },
      "month": { "$month": "$created_at" },
      "accepted": {
        "$concat": [
          { "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": [ "$accepted", 0, 1 ] } },
          { "$toLower": { "$substrCP": [ "$accepted", 1, { "$strLenCP": "$accepted" } ] } }
        ]
      }
    },
    "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { 
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            { "k": "_id", "v": { "year": "$_id.year", "month": "$_id.month" } },
            { "k": "$_id.accepted", "v": "$total" }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Most of this is handled by `$arrayToObject` and the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) pipeline stage. It may be noted that [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) usage here seems necessary since `$arrayToObject` is complaining if simply supplied the array literal as an argument. So instead we use an operator which returns an array from it's own given expression, and [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) seems to be the most brief notation.

This appears to be a bug ( to be confirmed ), but may well be just taken as intended usage since with most aggregation operators the array `[]` argument is usually intended for multiple arguments.

Also you appear to have a problem in your general [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement since the `"accepted"` values differ in case and will be treated differently by MongoDB. You can correct this with usage of operators like [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) and [`$toUpper`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/). Here I use some modern operators to make a consistent first letter as uppercase and the rest lowercase, but the basic case functions are available in all versions supporting `.aggregate()`.

Of course, post processing is very simple and can be done in any version. For JavaScript from the MongoDB shell it is as simple as follows:

```js
db.Booking.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "created_at": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$sort": { "created_at": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$created_at" },
      "month": { "$month": "$created_at" },
      "accepted": {
        "$concat": [
          { "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": [ "$accepted", 0, 1 ] } },
          { "$toLower": { "$substrCP": [ "$accepted", 1, { "$strLenCP": "$accepted" } ] } }
        ]
      }
    },
    "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
  }}
]).forEach(doc => {
  doc[doc._id.accepted] = doc.total;
  delete doc._id.accepted;
  delete doc.total;
  printjson(doc)
})
```

Both produce the same thing:

```js
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2017, "month" : 4 }, "Expired" : 25 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2017, "month" : 4 }, "Pending" : 390 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2017, "month" : 5 }, "Pending" : 1400 }
```

---

If you in fact wanted "both" the "Pending" and "Expired" keys within the grouped results, then that is much simpler:

```js
db.Booking.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "created_at": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "year": { "$year": "$created_at" },
      "month": { "$month": "$created_at" }
    },
    "Expired": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ { "$toLower": "$accepted" }, "expired" ] },
          "$total",
          0  
        ]
      }
    },
    "Pending": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ { "$toLower": "$accepted" }, "pending" ] },
          "$total",
          0  
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2017, "month" : 4 }, "Expired" : 25, "Pending" : 390 }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2017, "month" : 5 }, "Expired" : 0, "Pending" : 1400 }
```

Since there is a "fixed" format for the keys in the document any they do not vary, then this is a simple layout and we just use [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to decide which values to accumulate under each key with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

Comment: `MongoError: invalid operator '$substrCP'`

Comment: but I would like to have it group by month and year so that Expired and `Pending` in the same object

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul Please read the answer. You need MongoDB 3.4. Otherwise just iterate the cursor and use the `$toLower` method like the answer already says.

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul And your "question" shows exactly the output I have given.

Comment: fwiw, there are plenty of reasons to shape data this way in the db. I would primarily cite performance: it's much easier to offload this type of processing on the db, as with very large payloads, it could cause the server to hang while iterating through very large results. Granted, the code may be prohibitively difficult, but if it's an option, I personally would prefer it.